# In Clojure creating a function that creates 'n' JButtons each with different 'actionPerformed' method in other namespace

Tags: function, clojure, namespaces, parameter-passing

I have adapted this method from p.216 Joy of Clojure.

```
 (defn makeButton [txt func panel]
    (let [btn (JButton. txt) ] ;bfun (symbol func) ]
    (doto  btn
        (.addActionListener 
            (proxy [ActionListener] [] (actionPerformed [_] 
                (func))) ;(bfun)))
        ))
        (.add panel btn)
    ))
```

Plus this test code:

```
(defn fba [] (prn "fba"))
(defn fbb [] (prn "fbb"))
(def funs [fba fbb])
(def btnames ["B1" "B2"])
```

Buttons & actionPerformed are created thusly in a gui setup function:

```
(doseq [i (range (count btnames)) ] 
              (makeButton (get btnames i) (nth funs i) aJpanel))
```

This works as I want; clicking "B1" prints string "fba", etc. My difficulty arises when I want to attach to 'actionPerformed' something such as: `ns1.ns2/myFunction` instead of these simple cases (i.e. use a list/vector of several namespaced qualified functions). The exception reported is

> wrong number of args (0) passed to Symbol

From the 'makeButton' function above my attempt to solve this is commented out. What is an idiomatic clojure solution to this?

Comment: All you should need to do is replace one of the functions in `funs` with `ns1.ns2/myFunction`. If you try that (without modifying `makeButton` from the working version) what happens?

Comment: As an aside, I'd recommend using a map for your labels / functions: `(def foo {"B1" fba, "B2" fbb})` and then make your buttons as `(doseq [[label f] foo] (make-button label f panel))`

Comment: Thank you for useful advice on use of map. Sometimes one returns to old Java loop habits.

Comment: No worries, I'm still learning Clojure myself, so I try to find code that doesn't look "Clojure-like". :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me in the REPL. I'm using `clojure.pprint/pprint` as an example of a function that is in a different namespace:

```
(import '[javax.swing JFrame JPanel JButton]
        '[java.awt.event ActionListener])

(def panel (JPanel.))

(def frame (doto (JFrame. "Hello Frame")
             (.setContentPane panel)
             (.setSize 200 200)
             (.setVisible true)))

(defn make-button [label f panel]
  (let [button (JButton. label)]
    (doto button
      (.addActionListener
       (proxy [ActionListener] []
         (actionPerformed [evt]
           (f evt)))))
    (.add panel button)))

(make-button "One" clojure.pprint/pprint panel)

(.revalidate frame)
```

Comment: Very strange, but you are correct, your version works. Thank you for helping. Now I have to determine where I messed up.